# Trying to create a program that uses a Search Binary Tree to keep track of students- Java

Tags: java, queue, binary-search-tree

I am creating a program that uses a Search Binary Tree to keep track of students that get added and deleted from a list. The program reads a text file that contains certain a command (add, delete, calculate average,etc) followed by the student name, age, and gender. For example, the first line of the text file would be: E Jake 14 M. E would stand for enroll(add).

I'm having issues both conceptually and coding wise.

I have a queue class, a queueLL class that implements the queue class, I have a camper class that returns name, age, and gender, and compares each student name, and lastly I have my search binary tree class.

The issue is in the main class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


// delcaring some variables 
public class CampPosanivee {

  static String name;

  static String age;

  static String gender;

  static Camper camper = null;
  static double numkids;

  QueueLL q = new QueueLL();

  // creating a method to calculate averages
  static double avgkids(Camper[] campers) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < campers.length; i++)
      sum += campers[i].getNumKids();
    if (campers.length == 0)
      return 0;
    return sum / campers.length;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Camper c1 = new Camper("Kanga", "26", "F");
    Camper c2 = new Camper("Tigger", "28", "M");
    Camper c3 = new Camper("Pooh", "31", "M");
    Camper c4 = new Camper("Rabbit", "30", "M");
    Camper c5 = new Camper("Eeyore", "36", "M");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the name of File:");
    String filename = input.next();
    System.out.println();

    FileReader inFile = new FileReader(filename);
    Scanner sFile = new Scanner(inFile);
    String lineOfData;

    boolean q = true;
    while (q && sFile.hasNext()) {
      lineOfData = sFile.nextLine();
      if (lineOfData.substring(0, 1).equalsIgnoreCase("h")) {
        System.out.println("How to use this program:");
        System.out.println("Type E to enroll a new camper");
        System.out.println("Type W to withdraw a camper");
        System.out.println("Type D to display age and gender of camper");
        System.out.println("Type A to print average age of campers");
        System.out.println("Type L to list all campers name in alphabetical order");
        System.out.println("Type S to print the number of boys and girls camper");
        System.out.println("Type P to list all camper names in preorder");
        System.out.println("Type Q to quit program");
      } else if (lineOfData.substring(0, 1).equalsIgnoreCase("e")) {


        Scanner file = new Scanner(
                new FileReader("data.txt"));
        int n;
        n = file.nextInt();
        BST tree = new BST();
        for (int i = 0; n < i; i++) {
          Camper x = new Camper(file);
          System.out.println(x);
          tree.insert(x);
        }
      }

    }
  }
```

I don't think my implementation is correct and I am hitting a wall in terms of trying to finish the code. I get errors of trying pass the file argument in Camper

```
Camper x = new Camper(file);
```

The values define were 3 strings in my Camper Class file (name, age, gender). Any Help would be appreciated!

Edit Code for Camper:

```
public class Camper implements Comparable<Camper> {


private String name;
private String age; 
private String gender;
private double numKids; 

public Camper (String n, String a,String g){

   name = n; 
   age = a; 
   gender = g; 
}
public String getName()
{
return name; 
}

public String getAge()
{
return age; 
}

public String getGender()

{
return gender; 
}
public double getnumKids()
{
return numKids;
}
public int compareTo(Camper other)
{
   if (getName().compareTo(other.getName()) > 0) 
   {
      return 1; 
   }
   else if (getName().compareTo(other.getName()) < 0 )
   {
      return -1; 
   }
   else 
      return 0; 
}



}
```

Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: What is the Camper class? Can you attach its code?

Comment: Camper doesn't have the constructor with Scanner argument?

Comment: Okay, I added the code for camper. Hopefully, this bring some clarification.

Answer (score 0):

First off, they're called Binary Search Trees, not Search Binary Trees. :P

As for the actual error, you only have one constructor in the Camper class, and it takes three Strings - you're trying to pass it a file. It's not going to be able to guess how to parse that file and get the right three strings - you either need to do that in the calling code, or write another constructor that can do file handling.